# SQL Injection with mysql_escape_string multi-charset vulnerability to write an output file

Tags: mysql, sql, security, sql-injection, penetration-testing

Over the past week I've been trying to circumvent a SQL query using the PHP addslashes/mysql_escape vulnerability with multi character set languages.

Taking the following PHP code into consideration, I'm trying to manipulate the query with injection to write to an output file of my choice:

```
   $username = mysql_escape_string($_POST["puser"]);
   $password = mysql_escape_string($_POST["ppwd"]);

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
```

The database is using the gbk charset.

I know that by injecting a 0xbf27 I can escape a single quote as the mysql_escape_string function makes the code into a 0xbf5c27, however I can't figure out how to make a working SQL query to write an output file using this method.

Injecting into the password parameter the closest I can get is the following:

```
aaaa%Bf%27+UNION+SELECT+1+INTO+OUTFILE+%BF%27/tmp/sql.out
```

which derives an invalid syntax query as:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='000' and password='aaa縗' UNION SELECT 1 INTO OUTFILE 縗'/tmp/sql.log'
```

The invalid query is due to the character between the OUTFILE parameter and file name being generated as part of the injection.

From what I read in the MySQL documentation is stated that the quotes around the filename are mandatory.

Is there any way this can be exploited to write out arbitrary file contents?

Any thoughts are much appreciated.

mcgeezer

Comment: Did you try to inject only the quote character like: %27

Comment: Yes, that would get interpreted as \' so would not break the query.